# Assigning and incrementing a value during method call

Tags: java, increment, primitive

Can anyone explain me why such call doesn't increment my `i` value ?

```
int i = 0;
list.get(7 + (i = i++));
list.get(7 + (i = i++));
```

it leaves `i=0` instead of increment by one at least such that in the second call it is 1.

Comment: `i = i++` makes no sense, since `i++` does edit `i` value

Comment: What you actually wanted to write is `list.get(7 + i++)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i = i++` is like doing:

```
int old_i = i; 
i = i + 1;
i = old_i;
```

What is actually happening is that the value of `i++` is the value of `i` **before** the increment happens, then `i` will get the value of.. `i`.

In one line `i++` will use the *old value* of `i` and then it will increment it.

Answer (score 3):

`i = i++` assigns first and increments second

heres what the execution essentially looks like:

```
list.get(7 + (i = i)); //list.get(7);
i = i + 1; //i = 1
list.get(7 + (i = i); //list.get(8);
i = i + 1; //i = 2
```

`++i` will increment the variable first and assign second

Comment: "++i will increment the variable first and assign second" so why for i = (++i) compiler is giving me a warning: "The assignment to variable i has no effect" ?

Comment: because it will have no effect. It is a redundancy because i is assigned the incremented value during the postfix incrementing (++i). You simply need list.get(7+(++i));

Answer (score 1):

`i = i++` means that `i` will be assigned the old value of `i` which then will be incremented by 1. If you want to really increment your value, you should write either:

```
int i = 0;
list.get(7 + (i++));
list.get(7 + (i++));
```

or:

```
int i = 0;
list.get(7 + (i+1));
list.get(7 + (i+2));
```